# How to search in Quickblox Arrays

Tags: quickblox

I am using http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android#Search_operators to find keywords in "Array" data type.

But it searches by first string in array only. How to search among all strings in array?

```
public static void getNews(final Context context, final Handler handler, final int page) {
    ArrayList<String> catSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<NewsCategory> categories = Cache.getNewsCategories(context);
    for(NewsCategory category : categories) {
        if(Cache.isCategoryChecked(context, category.getId())) {
            catSearch.add(category.getId());
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> tagSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<NewsTag> tags = Cache.getNewsTags(context, Cache.SELECTED_TAGS);
    for(NewsTag tag : tags) {
        tagSearch.add(tag.getTitle());
    }

    QBRequestGetBuilder builder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    if(tagSearch.size() == 0) {
        builder.ctn("LangId", Cache.getNewsLanguage(context)).
                in("CategoryId", catSearch.toArray());
    } else {
        builder.ctn("LangId", Cache.getNewsLanguage(context)).in("Tags", tagSearch.toArray()).
                in("CategoryId", catSearch.toArray());
    }

    QBCustomObjects.getObjects("News", builder,
            new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBCustomObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBCustomObject> customObjects, Bundle params) {
                    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<News> newsArray = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QBCustomObject object : customObjects) {
                        try {
                            HashMap<String, Object> pairs = object.getFields();
                            String id = object.getCustomObjectId();
                            long created = object.getCreatedAt().getTime();
                            News news = new News(pairs, id, created);
                            newsArray.add(news);
                            Log.e("", "Tags: " + pairs.get("Tags"));

                            if (!news.getPhoto().equals("")) {
                                images.add(news.getPhoto());
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    Cache.saveNews(context, newsArray);

                    if (handler != null) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(6);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                    Helper.showErrorToast(context, errors);
                    if (handler != null) {
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

UPD:

We held some research and here is the results:

**1. When we search for tag "Русский":**

```
QBRequestGetBuilder builder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
builder.in("Tags", "Русский");
```

https://api.quickblox.com/data/News.json?Tags[in]=%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

**RESULTS:**

news id: 55b4a74f535c12b641004f3e; tags: [Русский,  советы]

news id: 55b91b78535c129a1d0039f2; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55ba9482535c1238ce003522; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55ba96c4535c1298ec0003fc; tags: [Русский,  советы]

news id: 55ba973f535c1298ec0004d7; tags: [Русский]

news id: 55ba9967535c12e2c00017f9; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55ba99e3535c1298ec00099f; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55bd592c535c12a8d6000327; tags: [Русский]

news id: 55bb32ae535c12e543006e15; tags: [Русский,  религия,  пятница,  Коран]

So, it was not searched for tag "Русский" when it is not a first tag in array. We have checked databse - we have some news with Tags ["Россия","Русский"]

**2. When we search for tags "Русский", "Томск":**

```
QBRequestGetBuilder builder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
        builder.in("Tags", "Русский", "Томск");
```

https://api.quickblox.com/data/News.json?Tags[in]=%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA

**3. When we search for tags "Томск", "Русский":**

```
QBRequestGetBuilder builder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
        builder.in("Tags", "Томск", "Русский");
```

https://api.quickblox.com/data/News.json?Tags[in]=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%2C%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

**RESULTS FOR 2 AND 3 THE SAME NOW:**

news id: 555c46736390d8a0ca03ab61; tags: [Томск,  Алмере]

news id: 555c46b26390d8a7ce01439e; tags: [Томск,  Алмере,  Нидерланды,  Россия]

news id: 555c50bf6390d8b66300dadf; tags: [Россия, Томская область, Томск]

news id: 555d7f5c6390d8eb8504df15; tags: [Россия, Томская область, Томск,  Russia,  Moscow,  Москва]

news id: 556454536390d894de005c22; tags: [Томск,  Россия]

news id: 55a905ba535c1207e600251d; tags: [Томск,  Россия]

news id: 55b4a74f535c12b641004f3e; tags: [Русский,  советы]

news id: 55b91b78535c129a1d0039f2; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55ba9482535c1238ce003522; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55ba96c4535c1298ec0003fc; tags: [Русский,  советы]

news id: 55ba973f535c1298ec0004d7; tags: [Русский]

news id: 55ba9967535c12e2c00017f9; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55ba99e3535c1298ec00099f; tags: [Русский,  Россия]

news id: 55bd592c535c12a8d6000327; tags: [Русский]

news id: 55bb32ae535c12e543006e15; tags: [Русский,  религия,  пятница,  Коран]

news id: 55666ac66390d8ce7900044f; tags: [Томск,  Россия]

Comment: Ok, can you post REST logs from logcat? because seems like REST API works okay, need to check what Android SDK generates

Comment: Igor, I have update my post

Answer (score 0):

According to that doc http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android#Search_operators

with arrays you can use only **in**, **nin** and **all** operators

**UPD**
For example, I have a class **Post** with a field **tags**. And a have a record where **tags=["man","golf","car"]**

This is my requests:

```
http://api.quickblox.com/data/Post.json?tags[in]=car&token=70f997fecf68b25f8992271b5f943503884f3f52

http://api.quickblox.com/data/Post.json?tags[in]=man&token=70f997fecf68b25f8992271b5f943503884f3f52

http://api.quickblox.com/data/Post.json?tags[in]=golf&token=70f997fecf68b25f8992271b5f943503884f3f52
```

They all return the same record:

```
{"class_name":"Post","skip":0,"limit":0,
  "items":[{"_id":"55ba0597535c12a4120011e8","_parent_id":"",
   "body":"How are you?",
   "created_at":1438254487,"tags":["man","golf","car"],
   "title":"best post","updated_at":1438254487,"user_id":291}]}
```

Comment: Yes, we have tried all of them, but they search by first row in arrays only.

Comment: Added an example, please check

Comment: Igor, thank you. I have update my question, can you check please.